# Generating PDF with PHP (TCPDF)

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF document in Label Size with PHP.
This works in principle, but I can not get the text under the barcode (code 128) placed correctly.
The text slips from a few letters into the next line, although there is still space.

Does anyone know and can help?
[image]

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
{  

    $name = "3359";
    $first = "Battery Battery Battery";
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_1d.php');
    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, array(38 ,23), true, 'UTF-8', false);  
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
    $pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 1);  
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 14);  
    $pdf->AddPage(array(38 ,23));  
    $content = '';  
    $content = "_________"; 
    $content2 = ''; 

$style = array(
    'position' => '',
    'align' => 'C',
    'stretch' => false,
    'fitwidth' => true,
    'cellfitalign' => '',
    
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false,
    'text' => false,
    'font' => 'helvetica',
    'fontsize' => 1,
    'stretchtext' => 2
);

$pdf->Cell(0, 0, '', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetXY(2.5,0.5);
$pdf->writeHTML($name);  
$pdf->SetX(0);
$pdf->write1DBarcode($name, 'C128A', '', '', 30, 6, 0.8, $style, 'N');

$pdf->SetX(2.5);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
$pdf->writeHTML($first);

$pdf->Output('label.pdf', 'I');  
}
```

Here should be as a test 3 times battery next to each other, the 3rd time it is "printed" on another page

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: I don't know much about TCPDF, having used only FPDF before. But as I understand, TCPDF is a sort of superset or branch of FPDF. So they might seem to work in a similar way. But my experience is that you yourself are fully responsible to make measurements on the page. I recon you check for [MultiCell](https://www.radmin.com/tcpdf/doc/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html#methodMultiCell) in TCPDF

Comment: Have you tried adding a border to the cell to see its physical representation within the PDF? It might not be as big as you are anticipating? I also use FPDF and I find positioning for that to be more forgiving for images vs cells as your barcode certainly gives the impression 3 x Battery would fit within its width but as I say Cells are not as straight forward.